# How to redirect unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For certain actions, like "signing in" or "sign up", I want to redirect user if she's already logged in.

Hence, I've created a method in the ApplicationController:

```
def kick_outable?
  if current_user
    redirect_to signout_path and return
  end
end
```

But appearantly I cannot use that method in actions where there already is a `render` or `redirect_to` in the action. From error message:

```
Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action.
```

**So, how do I solve this? How do I redirect someone that tries to access an action that shouldn't be able to?**

Comment: Are you using Devise?

Comment: No, handcrafted authoring and authorisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that method as a before_filter (do not invoke that method in an action) and should work as you expects.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Enrique's answer. The execution of a method in controller continues even after render or redirect statements. So having multiple of those does not work unless the execution is stopped after one of them via a return.

```
# This works because it stops execution after first redirect if not current_user
def index
  unless current_user
    redirect_to root_path and return
  end

  redirect_to user_path 

end



# This does not work as execution continues after check_user method

def check_user
  unless current_user
    redirect_to root_path and return
  end
end

def index  
  check_user  
  redirect_to user_path     
end
```